# Certain Drupal Backend Processes redirect to old domain

Tags: php, redirect, drupal

Recently, after finishing our new drupal site, we made a copy of it to use as a staging site.  We assigned it to a different url (`new.domain.com/site` versus `old.domain.com/site`).

As recommended, I changed the `$base_url` in the settings.php file to point to `new.domain.com/site` and that fixed most of the issues. The problem now is, whenever I make changes in the drupal backend, it wants to redirect back to `old.domain.com/site`. It looks like the change does go through, but it's still gets confusing and is an issue.

Where would I go to fix this? I tried the .htaccess already and it doesn't offer any clues.

Comment: Which backend processes are you having problems with, editing content, site configuration?

Comment: Cleared all the caches?

Comment: Specifically: editing menu links, adding new content, just about anything that ask Drupal to redirect to another page.

Comment: I was able to clear the cache via drush but the problem is still there.

Comment: Could part of the issue be that it's might still be pointing to the old.domain.com/site 's database ?